# How would you find the rate of change of momentum if we also assumed the mass was changing?

Tags: forces, kinematics, rocket-science, calculus

So, this is a question that just came to me. We all know that the derivative of momentum with respect to time is the definition of a force. 
$$
\frac{{\rm d}p}{{\rm d}t}=\frac{{\rm d}mv}{{\rm d}t}=m\frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}t}=ma 
$$
However, that's assuming that the mass remains *constant*. What if the mass was changing? Such as if we had a rocket that lost like 90% of its mass as fuel? Well then, wouldn't the mass also be a variable there, so you wouldn't be able to just factor it out and treat it as a constant.

So how exactly would you find the force applied then?

UPDATE: I took calculus and understand why this question is pretty stupid

Comment: $F=\frac{dp}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}$.

Comment: *"Such as if we had a rocket"* - In the case of a rocket (ideal case, in vacuum etc. etc.), there is *no* external force and thus no change in the momentum of the *center of mass*.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri.....It depends on what you define as the system...

Comment: @DJohnM, I honestly thought that the parenthetical would head off at the pass the objection that you raised.  Would you clarify your comment with an example?

Answer (score 2):

You would simply just use the product rule. The definition of net force $\mathbf{F}$ is always given by

$$ \sum_i \mathbf{F}_i = \frac{d\mathbf{p}}{d t} = \frac{d}{dt} m(t)\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}\frac{dm}{dt} + m(t)\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}.$$

Comment: This may be correct mathematically but is not a correct application of Newton's second law.  The reason for that is given here and the links therein. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53980/second-law-of-newton-for-variable-mass-systems