How exactly does Newton's second law work?
I had to do a reading on rollercoasters in class and it includes Newton's second law. Firstly, the reading states that acceleration depends on the magnitude of the force and the  mass of the object, which definitely makes sense. However, then it begins describing the force as something that is caused by mass and acceleration, which seems like it goes against this. More specifically, it states "The coaster cars and your body have mass. The gravity provides acceleration. This causes force." It also implies that the track itself impacts the force when it says "The track directs the force and the cars." Basically, I'm confused if force is a cause of acceleration, or if force results from mass, acceleration, and the track itself. Thanks and I hope this makes sense. Edit: I understand my question has been associated with a previous question, but I am doing much simpler science than the one highlighted in the other question and can't understand it.

Very good question, but it has been asked before https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/785490/

I tried looking at the other question, but I am not learning science as advanced as that yet, so I can't understand it.
