# D'Alembert's principle when the mass of the particles are changing

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, mass, constrained-dynamics

In the book of *Classical Mechanics* by Goldstein, at page 19, while deriving D'Alembert's principle, the author assumes that

$$\dot p = m \ddot r.$$

However, when the mass of the bodies also changes, is the principle still correct, or can be corrected? If so, how?

Comment: If one googles this the first thing to come up is the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle) which explains what to do in this case in its first section.

Comment: @jacob1729 I was so hopeless to find an answer that I didn't even thought googling it. Thanks a lot for the reference.

Comment: If the mass of the body changes with respect to time then you need to use product rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mechanics theorems, the material particles considered are universally assumed to have constant mass. If you have a situation where a body or a particle changes its mass, you have to model it as a collection of smaller particles of constant mass which leave or become part of the control volume associated with the original body. A body has to have constant mass for the mainstream Newton or other mechanical laws to be directly applicable.

There is no general principle for systems where particles change their mass, because what such particles and systems of them will do **depends on details of *how* the particles lose their mass**. Does the particle eject a stream of smaller particles, all in a single one direction? If so, which direction then? Or does it eject them in all directions equally? Net reactive force on the original particle will depend on these details and so will the evolution of system of such particles.

Don't get me wrong, Newton's laws or D'Alembert principle can deal with variable mass systems. However, the way this is done is careful analysis of individual particle forming the system, each of which has to have constant mass.

The suggestion in the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle that one should differentiate mass of the particles is a very strange one. It is probably based on mistaken belief that $\mathbf F=\dot{\mathbf p}$ is universally valid expression of second law, even for variable mass systems. However, one *does not* differentiate mass with respect to time to apply Newton's second law, *ever*. See also my answer here:

[Second law of Newton for variable mass systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53980/second-law-of-newton-for-variable-mass-systems/142773#142773)

Comment: If $F = \dot p$ is not universally valid expression, then what it is ?

Comment: In non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics, $\mathbf F_{ext}=m\mathbf a$ for any body that does not change its mass. For bodies that change their mass, there is no simple universal equation, it depends. In case of a rocket, if mass is ejected in one direction with terminal velocity $\mathbf c$ with respect to the rocket, then we have the rocket equation of motion $\mathbf F_{ext} + \dot{m}\mathbf c = m\mathbf a$

Comment: Then there must be some cases when the body change its mass, the net force acting on the body is not equal to $\dot p$. Is there any chance that you can provide such an example, or give at least a reference to it ?

Comment: Consider a rocket that leaks fuel through two holes on opposing sides of the cylindrical fuel tank, and the mass loss rate and speed of the flow is the same for both holes. This loss of mass decreases net momentum of the rocket, but it does not in any way change net force acting on the rocket.

Comment: Well that makes sense. Thanks a lot for the answer.