# Reverse Rocket Equation Not Valid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, rocket-science

Consider a truck of mass $M$ on a sheet of ice; assume that friction between the tire and the ground is negligible. Suppose you (fixed to the ground) begin throwing rocks of mass $m$ at speed $u$, rate $r$, at the truck (continuously), where they collect on back of the truck. Show that the speed of the truck is given by $$v = u\left(1 - \frac{M}{M_{total}}\right).$$

My question is, I thought this would be kind of a "reverse" rocket equation question.
So instead of losing mass, the truck is gaining mass, so the speed would be given by the rocket equation
$$v = u \ln \left(\frac{M_{total}}{M}\right).$$
But clearly, that's not what the problem says.
Could someone explain to me what I'm not getting? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to have a look here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/732835. Please, follow the whole derivation

Answer (score 2):

In your problem, all the speeds appear to be relative to the ground.  The rocks are at speed $u$ relative to the ground, so the limiting case is where the truck nearly reaches that speed.

In the rocket equation, the exhaust speed is relative to the rocket.  So there is no fixed maximum speed that the vehicle is constrained to reach.

Comment: Right... but wouldn't it still follow the same derivation though? The change in momentum is given by $\frac{dm}{dt} = M\frac{dv}{dt} + v\frac{dm}{dt}$, considering there's no external forces, $M\frac{dv}{dt} = -v\frac{dm}{dt}$, integrate... This leads to just the reverse rocket equation.

Comment: @littleeinsteinplus:  The $v$ on the right-hand side of your equation is the velocity of the ejected (ingested?) mass relative to the rocket/truck at a particular time.  In the case of a rocket, that is a fixed exhaust velocity $v_\text{ex}$.  In the case of the truck, it should be $u-v$, where $v$ is the velocity of the truck at that moment.

Comment: Ahh I get it - thanks so much!