Force becomes infinite when a vehicle stops and reverses direction
I want to simulate the horizontal motion of a vehicle driven by an engine of given power P. For start in the simplified case with no friction (no dissipative forces).
My problem is with P = Fv: Suppose the vehicle was launched backwards with an initial velocity -v0 while the engine pushes forward -- it will decelerate, stop, and then reverse direction. When the vehicle changes direction v = 0, so if I calculate the force F = P/v I get infinity.
I asked an AI assistant and it said to limit the magnitude of the force. But it doesn't work nicely, the force graph still has a weird shape around the stopping point.
I need the force for the case when I introduce drag: F_acceleration = F_engine + F_drag, where F_drag = - k*v. My goal is to simulate a very simple vehicle with an interactive "acceleration pedal" (gas pedal), to show that it does not control the acceleration of the vehicle.
What is the customary way of dealing with this 'infinite force at rest` problem in numerical simulations (an ODE solver)?

Isn't $P = F v$ the power supplied by a force $F$ to an object moving at constant velocity $v$?

It is true that F = P/v but at the moment when $v=0$ the power is also zero. That means $F= 0/0$ and that is undefined rather than infinite. You need a different way to calculate the force, and that way is just Newton's second law $F=ma$. Since the acceleration is finite the force is finite as well.

@JohnRennie So the power of the engine drops to 0 when the vehicle reverses? I find it difficult to picture this, I mean I would still hear the engine working and delivering power during the whole process.

You are just using the wrong modelling assumptions. Engines don't do this. Even from train locomotives, the standard treatment is that the force is constant for low speeds and power is constant for high speeds. So, you have to break the modelling into two speed regimes and deal with things that way. The thing as you are doing now is just nonsense.

@naturallyInconsistent So the answer is that the engine of a vehicle cannot physically output constant power in the described scenario (e.g., a boat launched backwards, while its engine tries to move it forwards)?

I asked an AI assistant and it said... Why ask an AI that doesn't really know anything about physics (they just "know" how to put words together to make a sentence) instead of, say, a textbook?

Your required force is NEVER infinite.
$$F={\frac P v}$$
is valid when $v=constant$.
Otherwise, $F=m \times a $ is dominant, where a is the acceleration at that instant.
($F= m \times a + {\frac {dm} {dt}} v$ , to be exact) .
As nowhere the direction of acceleration changes during the retardation part, $v$ clearly is not constant but we can assume $a$ is. If $a$ is function of time, then use calculus and derive the above. I hope that resolves the conflict of infinite force.
Edit:-  The OP had some doubts regarding this so let's clear it. First of all you need to know the mass of the vehicle. Knowing the power is useless as we know that displacement is zero. So, literally force can be anything. You are actually trying to find an answer to an equation with 2 variables with only one equation. If you don't know the mass. I'm sorry, friend, you can't the calculate the force, considering the data, you mentioned in the comment.

The mass of the vehicle is constant, so dm/dt=0. At time t I know x, v, a, Pengine. How do I calculate all these at t+dt (supposing that Pengine is constant during dt)? F = ma at t, but how do I compute a at t+dt, knowing that the body received Pengine×dt energy? My approach is this: F = Pengine/v; a = F/m; v += a dt, x += v dt. But the first step is problematic: Pengine/v shoots to infinity when the vehicle changes direction. What other approach do you suggest?

Let's go step by step. Ur correct that here dm/dt =0. I had just given the full formula for a complete idea. I would ask you why you need t+dt, though? Oh, seems I get it let's make it correct. See the edit and upvote if it helped. But before making an edit, let me ask you, don't you know the mass? And yh, 0/0 is undefined not infinite.

Your equation for force is misleading. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142773/186128

@HiddenBabel It is not at all misleading. The question says Newtonian mechanics and not about relativity. It's completely okay in relativity. Because here, mass is constant. Although I shouldn't say this, but the OP must be explained in simple words as you can judge by the question or comments. Please bear with him by being as simple as possible.

The mass is known. A vehicle of mass m is driven by an engine of power P on a road with drag −k⋅v. In general, for v ≠ 0, I can solve the differential equation P = m⋅v⋅dv/dt + k⋅v². The problem is when v = 0, because then the equation becomes P = 0, which has no solution for P ≠ 0. The difficulty is present even when there is no drag (P = m⋅v⋅dv/dt), that's why I presented here this simpler case.

Here's how the simulation looks: https://ibb.co/n6p9VZm First the engine power goes up lineraly, then plateaus, then goes to negative. The vehicle accelerates rapidly, then slower (constant power), then it decelerates. Everything goes smoothly until the vehicle tries to change direction, at about t = 23 seconds. There the simulation goes bonkers, because of the 1/v term

In this case, please consider the force and not the power, as it is more fundamental than the power at low velocities. When real vehicles change direction nothing of this sort happens, because they experience a linear force without any change in acceleration or jerk.

@Ritzthephysibeast I know how to solve the problem when the force is given. But I want to simulate the case of a vehicle having a gas pedal that controls the power of the engine. Not the force. This is the point I made in a discussion: "the gas pedal sets the engine's power", and I want to model such a mechanical system. Meantime I realised that you are right, P = 0 when v = 0. So my problem is not exactly at v = 0, but when v approaches 0. Then the equation P = m⋅v⋅a + k⋅v²... wait, I think I can just differentiate it one more time. I'll just try it now.

Yes, the graph is not continuous at v=0. So, you can't use definite integral. Please mind this. Otherwise, it's not impossible. Tell me what happened please.
